# How to update gridview columns in viewstate

Tags: asp.net

I have 4 rows in `GridView`, each row having 9 columns, `GridView` is maintained in `Viewstate`. In `GridView` row two columns are `TextBox`-fields.

When i change  the `TextBox`-field then  three coumns are reflected in `GridView`. So, i need to know how to store these columns in  `Viewstate` instead of row. 
Please tell me how to do.

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Your controls are stored in viewstate between interactings to the server. This is how ASP.NET know that a control has changed. (The value is not equal the value in viewstate)